# ReactJS component won't update after first API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I recently started to discover ReactJS. I have a simple Spring Boot api which has a few methods. One of these returns a list of objects. I get these in my frontend by using Axios to make the HTTP call.

```
export function getItems() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    await client.get('items').then((result) => {
      setItems(result.data);
    });
  }, []);
  return items;
```

The items are mapped in a gallery component and shown on screen. Next to this, I have an addItem function which posts an item object obtained through a form to my api.

```
export async function addPet(newPet) {
      await client.post(
        '/pets',
        newPet,
      );
    }
```

My AddPet component is loaded inside my Gallery component. The form is shown on the right side of the screen and when I click the "Add Item" button, I want the item to be added and my list of items reloaded to show the newly added item. Right now, I can not get this working in a correct way. If I remove the  "[]" from the final part of my useEffect() in my getItems() functions, everything seems to work but in reality the app is making the getItems call over and over again. If I add "[]", the call is only made once at the start, but will not re-render the gallery component when an item is added. The handleSubmit() for my "Add item" button is as follows:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    const newItem = new Item();
    newItem .name = formValue.name;
    newItem .image = formValue.image;
    newItem .pitemText = formValue.itemText;
    addItem(newItem);
  };
```

So my question here is: how can I get that gallery component to re-render whenever I add a new item or delete one of the items? I figure I need a way to change the state of the component but I can't seem to get it done.

Comment: `getItems` shouldn't use state at all. It should just be a function that returns some data. Let your component manage the state when you call that function and get some data back.

Comment: From your Gallery component, pass an `addItem` function down to your form component as prop. In the Gallery, when the form calls `addItem`, make the POST to update the item, then make the GET to load the updated list.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I moved the state out of my ItemService and into my Gallery. However I encounter a different issue now. When I want to add an item or remove one, I can get this working perfectly through localhost. Once I deploy (in this case I deployed the backend to Heroku and the frontend to Netlify, it fails. Sometimes it works, but mostly it doesn't. If I move my button out of my <form> tag, it does work but the Gallery doesn't get re-rendered. When it doesn't work, the network tab in Firefox tells me NS_BINDING_ABORTED for the corresponding calls

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `useEffect` (the `Array`) has an important role: the items in that array trigger the `useEffect` to re-run.

Some cases:

- `useEffect(() => {}, [])`: runs once, after the component is mounted
- `useEffect(() => {}, [var1, var2,..., varn])`: runs when `var1` or `var2` or `varn` is updated
- `useEffect(() => {})`: runs on every completed re-render (default behavior)

More on `useEffect`: [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

So, your code works as expected:

```
useEffect(() => {
  client.get('items').then((result) => {
    setItems(result.data);
  });
}, []); // -> runs once, when component is mounted

useEffect(() => {
  client.get('items').then((result) => {
    setItems(result.data);
  });
}, [item]); // -> runs when the variable named item changes
```

you need to organize your code in such a way, that this `useEffect` hook can run on the update of the variable whose change you want to watch.

Comment: first parameter on useEffect is a function but it cant be async function @muka.gergely

Comment: @ndotie you are absolutely right, I update the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

dont pust async as the first parameter of useEffect hook as below, wont work well

```
useEffect(async () => {
  await client.get('items').then((result) => {
    setItems(result.data);
  });
}, []);
```

instead you can use external function or IIEF function as below

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    await client.get('items').then((result) => {
     setItems(result.data);
    });
  })()
  
}, []);
```